# Codeception: How to continue testcase on url of previous testcase?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using codeception with selenium2.

And developing a data driven testing for which I require the url opened by first testcase (cept file) to be used by second testcase (cept file), that is, the tests of second cept file should continue on the same browser.

Please help me on how to do it.

Thanks,
Lakshmi

Comment: You can use 

string sOLdurl = driver.getcurrenturl();
You can store this url in some text file.

and read the string from text file in your 2nd test .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a private variable in class level like,

```
private String url = null;
```

and capture the 'url' in your first test case like,

```
url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

and in your second test case use this 'url' string to navigate to last test case 'url' like,

```
driver.navigate().to(url);
```